# Guided post type create based on category tree

Tags: custom-post-types, forms

I’ve created a new Post Type ‘Ticket’ with a Category Taxonomy. 
Categories have Sub Category up to N level.

What I’d like to do is let the front end user create a ticker where he would be guided by the system. The guide would setp by step select the correct catogry acodin to the category tree
The user would have some ‘Tile’ – Square image + title. 
Each time he clics on a Tile, the N-1 level would appear as Tile as well to the N level depending the Categories.

Category :

- A

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3

    - y
    - x
    - y
- B

  - 4
  - 5

    - i
    - o
    - p
  - 6

At the end he would be able to submit the post type item creating an entry in the backend .

The goal is to have something working the same way as this site : https://www.monsupervoisin.fr/mission/poster

Do you have any idea how I could create something like this ? Maybe there is already a plugin but I wouldn’t find it.

I’m a beginner with only basis  development skills. Where would you advise me to start this process ?

Edit : 
Actually I think I found a 'simple' solution.

I download a bootstrap [template](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApG1DjiT2yKRhs5BF-zjabjW325T4Q) with some JQuery and gallery filter.

I modifyed the HMTL in order to have another filter as a result of the first filter. 
My 2 difficulties are 
- How to isolate the minimum code to do that. Especially in the JQuery as I have no knowledge about it
- How can I, when I have my 3 simple codes 'HTML','CSS' and 'Jquery' add them on wordpress. I triyed to add some JQuery but doesn't seem to be easy.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to look into directory listing theme or plugin.

Comment: You can search to see whether there's something like this already built that meets your needs - theme or plugin - but it sounds specific enough that you will likely need to pay a developer if you want this exact functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the information i'll look into this. 
Could we look into a Filtering as Masonry but with 2 steps ? The first one would be a subcategory result and step by step to the final one.